# How to place DataTables column filter on top

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables latest version.  I want to use individual column filter on every table so am using the column filter plugin but am getting search boxes in footer only.  I want to place in the header

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
var  oTable=$("#example").dataTable({
       "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "aLengthMenu": [[5, 15, 50, 100], [5, 15, 50, "l00"]],
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
         "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sDom": '<"top"if>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">'

    }).columnFilter({"sPlaceHolder":"head :before",
    "aoColumns": [{ "type": "text" }, { "type": "text" }, null, null, null, null, { "type": "text" }, null, { "type": "text" }, { "type": "text" }, { "type": "text" },
```

How can I place it on the top of my table?

Answer (score 38):

## Method 1 (CSS)

You could change the CSS to

```
tfoot {
    display: table-header-group;
}
```

## Method 2 (Javascript)

Put the filter row stuff into the THEAD as TDs (not THs) and change

```
$("tfoot input")
```

to

```
$("thead input")
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but am sorry am not getting 2nd method..can u explain briefly..

Comment: You could use method 1 which is the simplest. http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter.html will tell you more about method 2

Comment: CSS - great suggestion, simple and effective. Thanks.

Comment: @asprin - super! Thanks!

Comment: Its working in chrome and firefox but not in IE..Aware!

Answer (score 16):

You can move it to the top of your table by adding the parameter 'sPlaceHolder'

```
}).columnFilter({
    sPlaceHolder: "head:after",
    aoColumns: [ ...
```

Answer (score 12):

Simply use the following javascript code ( here 'example' being the id of your table ):

```js
$('#example tfoot tr').insertAfter($('#example thead tr'))
```

Comment: This help me fix the issue.

Answer (score 10):

In CSS you can use

`display: table-header-group; //on tfoot`

and

`display: table-row-group; //on thead`

You'll get them positioned like this:

```
tfoot
thead
tbody
```

Comment: I had a related problem, except I wanted 'thead' on top, 'tfoot' just below it, and the rest of the rows after that.  Since 'thead' was already at the top of the HTML, and 'tfoot' just after it, setting 'display: table-row-group' on the 'tfoot' element worked just fine.  It now displays correctly on Chrome and IE10.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#mytable thead td').each( function () {
        var title = $('#mytable thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
});
$("#mytable thead input").on( 'keyup change', function () {
        table
            .column( $(this).parent().index()+':visible' )
            .search( this.value )
            .draw();
});
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `sPlaceHolder` option :

```
sPlaceHolder: "head:before"
```

example :

```
dataTable.columnFilter({
  sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
  aoColumns: [
      { type: "select" },  
      { type: "select" },        
      { type: "select" },  
      { type: "select" },  
      { type: "select" }
  ]
});
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/JNxj5/**

Answer (score 1):

```
  CSS:  
 tfoot input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
 tfoot {
display: table-header-group;}

 Script:
 $(document).ready(function() {
// Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
$('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
} );

// DataTable
 var table = $('#example').DataTable();

// Apply the search
 table.columns().every( function () {
    var that = this;

    $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
        if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
            that
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
        }
    } );
} );
```

} );

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain how this solves the OP's problem, and to explain what the code does. Code only answers are discouraged on SO. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

`this.footer()` to `this.header()`

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.