# How to put filter of renderDataTable at the top in R shiny

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

I am using `renderDataTable` in R & Shiny to present my data, but the filter is positioned at the bottom of table. Is there any way to put it at the top of the table? Thanks in advance!

BTW, where can I find the option list of `renderDataTable`?

```
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Table",tableOutput("values")),
      tabPanel("Tree Plot",plotOutput("plot")),
      tabPanel("Segment Data",dataTableOutput("obs"))
```

I'm not familiar with CSS, can anyone give me some advice on how to edit CSS inside R function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This : [How to place DataTables column filter on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629060/how-to-place-datatable-column-filter-on-top) : can help you with the CSS you'll need to modify to get the filter at the top.

You can look here : https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/blob/master/012-datatables/server.R : for how to use the `renderDataTable` options and you should be able to see the correlation between the way those options are set and the [options list](https://datatables.net/usage/options) for the jQuery DataTables proper.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not familiar with CSS, where can I edit that inside R function?

Comment: I haven't been able to replicate this in my shiny page. What do I need to pass to the options list?

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to modify the CSS. with this line

```
tags$head(tags$style("tfoot {display: table-header-group;}"))
```

You put this into your ui.R file like this

```
,tabPanel("MeSH"          ,tags$head(tags$style("tfoot {display: table-header-group;}"))
    ,fluidRow( ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I know very little of css and I prefer to do as many as possible from the core script that I don't need to worry about making changes to the cosmetic thing here or there later. So I used the following approach by setting "filter = 'top'" when calling renderDataTable() on server. No CSS required at all.

```
mainPanel("Data",
           dataTableOutput("datatbl"))
```

server.R

```
# create data table output
output$datatbl <- DT::renderDataTable(

  #data
  dt2(), rownames = FALSE,

  # column filter on the top
  filter = 'top', server = TRUE,

  # autoWidth
  options = list(autoWidth = TRUE))
```

Note that I only use renderDataTable() to call the function, to use arguments in the function we cannot write it as programming codes in {}, I guess. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Forgot to mention, `dt2()` is just a reactive object I created in my own project, you can test using a preloaded dataset, e.g. mtcar, iris etc.