# Edit CSS of renderDataTable in R shiny

Tags: css, r, datatables, shiny

I am using R shiny to present data and  want to move filter of datatable from bottom to top. I have already got answer from stackoverflow suggests to change CSS. But I am not familiar with CSS, can anyone tell me how to modify CSS in `renderDataTable` function? Thanks!

reference link: [How to place DataTables column filter on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629060/how-to-place-datatable-column-filter-on-top)

I tried the following, but doesn't work:

```
  output$obs <- renderDataTable({data()},
                                options = list(aoColumnDefs = list(list(fnFilter$tfoot(display = "table-header-group"))))
                                )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure that's the best way to do it but you can "overwrite" the css of "tfoot" elements :

Using for example this line in your Ui :

```
tags$head(tags$style("tfoot {display: table-header-group;}"))
```

Though, it can be a problem if you have other tables with footer which you don't want at the top of the tables.

Comment: Great!Thanks! That might be a problem in the future, but so far is good.

Comment: BTW, how to understand this line? tags$head(tags$style...) is a fix syntax or you get from CSS code? Thx!

Comment: Here I include a css class into a style tag within the head. It's like writing `<head><style>tfoot {display: table-header-group;}</style></head>` in a HTML file. And `tags$head` or `tags$style` are shiny functions returning HTML.