# Display column filters as a second row in the header

Tags: jquery, datatables

I use this code to display column filters in the footer and it works great, see https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );

    // DataTable
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    // Apply the search
    table.columns().every( function () {
        var that = this;

        $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                that
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        } );
    } );
} );
```

Problem is that I want the filter just below the header instead of the footer. I tried to change position of `tfoot` tag using css but it did not worked on IE.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629060/how-to-place-datatables-column-filter-on-top/17629080

Comment: Nup,  none of it is working ON Internet Explorer